# how can we send an image in the body of the mail using any of the mail utilities in Linux

Tags: linux, mailx, jpeg

How can we send an image in the body of a mail with rich text / HTML.

I tried to get from few of the links , but i am not able to get complete solution. I tried below code but no luck

```
mpack -s "TEST mail" -c image/jpeg Abc158.jpg <MASKED>@abc@gmail.com
```

Please help me with any suggestion

Comment: You have an answer to your question on the next link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706891/embedding-image-in-html-email

Comment: @YoMismo. Thanks a lot for the reply. It seems they are trying to run the code in oracle , can it be used to run in linux ?

Comment: The important part in your case is to embed the image tag in your body and add a header informing you are sending an html. Something like `echo "<img src=\"data:image/gif;base64, -your base64imghere-\" alt=\"img_alt_name\" />"|mail -a "Content-Type: text/html" -s test youremailaddres@yourserver.com` should work, but the tests I have done with Outlook doesn't work though it might with other mail clients (I haven't tested), you might need to adapt the body content to something Outlook will accept.

Comment: @YoMismo. In this command , where can i pass the image file name ?

Comment: @YoMismo. This is going as an attachment , but i require the image as in a body of a mail

Comment: You can't pass a filename, if you do that it will be an attachment. For the image to be part of the body instead of an attachment it has to be passed as a base64 encoding. You can encode your image using `base64 yourimage.gif/jpg/png....` replace the part of the command stated on the other comment as -your base64imgher- by `$((base64 /path/to/yourimgfile/filename))`